# Update if not exist in vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Can anyone help me to fix my query. I want to update my data if the `syscode` is not exist but when I try to update `sysdesc` it failed because the `syscode` exist already.

```
    Dim query As String
    Dim rowsAffected As Integer
    query = "UPDATE tbl_sysname SET syscode = @code, sysdesc = @desc " & _
        "WHERE id = @id AND NOT EXISTS  (SELECT syscode FROM tbl_sysname WHERE " & _
        "syscode = @code) "

    cmd = New SqlCommand(query, cn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCode.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@desc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtDesc.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lblId.Text

    rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    'MsgBox(rowsAffected)

    If rowsAffected >= 1 Then
        'reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        MsgBox("Update Successfully")
        LVSysName.Items.Clear()
        'reader.Close()
        GetLvData() 'This will display the data of LvSysName
    Else
        MsgBox("Failed to Update")
    End If
```

I want to avoid the duplication of `syscode` at the same time i can update  `sysdesc`.
Help me to fix my query or give me a suggestion on what should I do

Comment: why an update of `sysdesc` is influenced by an existence of `syscode`?

Comment: when i update the `sysdesc` the `rowsAffected` will return 0 because of `NOT EXIST` function

Comment: ok, so you want update `sysdesc` even though the `syscode` exists in the database?

Comment: yes, but i want to avoid the duplication of `syscode` also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use two `UPDATE` statements for this. There is no way to do it in one go.

```
UPDATE tbl_sysname 
SET syscode = @code
WHERE id = @id AND 
  NOT EXISTS  (SELECT syscode FROM tbl_sysname WHERE syscode = @code)

UPDATE tbl_sysname 
SET sysdesc = @desc
WHERE id = @id
```